# Load multiple frames into psf file in VMD

Tags: vmd

How can I open a psf file in vmd and then load for this psf file multiple frames (dcd files) using line commands only ? I have like hundreds of dcd files and I don't want to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using catdcd to join the dcd files together first. http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Development/MDTools/catdcd/

Then you can just load one giant dcd file with your psf file.

To use catdcd:
`catdcd -o output_file.dcd file1.dcd file2.dcd ... last_file.dcd`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with the following?

`mol new yourfile.psf waitfor all
mol addfile yourfile1.dcd waitfor all
mol addfile yourfile2.dcd waitfor all
...
mol addfile yourfileN.dcd waitfor all`

if you have hundreds of dcd files you can create the list of vmd commands using something like the following in a bash shell:

`for i in *dcd ; do printf "mol addfile %s waitfor all\n" $i ; done > your_vmd_script.tcl`

and source that after you have opened your psf in vmd:

`mol new yourfile.psf waitfor all
source your_vmd_script.tcl`

but make sure that the amount of data you are loading does not exceed the memory of your system, otherwise it will start to swap to disk and become unresponsive.